# CSS page-id child

Tags: css, wordpress, parent-child

I need to style element by page-id. I use for it this:

```
.page-id-34 .gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item { }
```

It is possible to style the same, but in relation to all child of page id 34?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean style all children elements inside of class `page-id-34`? If so you can use the wildcard selector `*`

Comment: Yes. I have page-id-34 and it has child pages. I would like to apply the style to all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got to that. I use:

```
.parent-pageid-34 .gallery-columns-9 .gallery-item { }
```

and it works!

Thank you for your participation.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wildcard to match all descendants of an element:

```
.page-id-34 * {
    color: red;
}
```

If you want to style only direct div elements for example it would be

```
.page-id-34 > div {
    color: red;
}
```